# Currency with fractional cents in a list box

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am building a Shopping Program - msAccesss 2016. Some of the items to buy are electrical components that have prices like $0.06100 if at least 10 are purchased. 
I am trying to display this the quantity and unit price in a list box. The list box rounds the price to cents. Anybody know of a way to display the entire $0.06100 in the list box? It displays OK in the datasheet view of the table and in a datasheet view of the query that is bound to the list box.

More detail:
The part of the Shopper that contains this information is a table called PricesLists. It has:

1. RecNo (autonumber for primary key)
2. VendorNo - foreign key to the Vendor table - the row represents the vendor's price.
3. PartNo - foreign key to the Parts table - the row represents the vendor's price for the part.
4. Quantity - at least the number of parts that must be ordered to get the price
5. Price - the price of the item to 5 decimal place US dollars.
6. LastChangedDate - actually timestamp of last change to this row.

The parts catalog function of the program starts by bringing up a find screen for the all of the parts. The user determines the part and vendor that is desired and selects it. That is when the form that is giving me trouble is displayed. It is bound to the part data and has a list box that displays the Prices with the quantity discounts in a list box. I get the data from the vendor's website and add it to the PricesLists table. As each row is added it is displayed in the list box. 
Price is defined as Currency in the PricesLists table with 5 decimal places.

I could not find any discussion of this problem on the internet anywhere. So I am the only one or it is easy and I am missing something simple. I am using vba to drive the forms and set up list boxes and other controls, so a vba solution will be just what I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use FormatCurrency([Expression], [Number Of Digits]) or FormatNumber([Expression], [Number Of Digits]).  Both will round the [Expression] to the [Number Of Digits] as a String

> FormatCurrency([0.06100], 5) returns "$0.06100"
>
> FormatNumber([0.06100], 5) returns "$0.06100"

Here are there method signatures taken from **MSDN**

[FormatCurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Function FormatCurrency(
   ByVal Expression As Object,
   Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Integer = -1,
   Optional ByVal IncludeLeadingDigit As TriState = TriState.UseDefault,
   Optional ByVal UseParensForNegativeNumbers As TriState = TriState.UseDefault,
   Optional ByVal GroupDigits As TriState = TriState.UseDefault
) As String
```

[FormatNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Function FormatNumber(
   ByVal Expression As Object,
   Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Integer = -1,
   Optional ByVal IncludeLeadingDigit As TriState = TriState.UseDefault,
   Optional ByVal UseParensForNegativeNumbers As TriState = TriState.UseDefault,
   Optional ByVal GroupDigits As TriState = TriState.UseDefault
) As String
```

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that a listbox displays text only, thus any numeric source field is casted to text using the default format from the Windows settings.

To get in control, do the formatting in the source, thus change

```
Select ProductId, Price, Description From Table
```

to:

```
Select ProductId, Format(Price, "$0.000000"), Description From Table
```

However, as you store the values as Currency, you will never get more than four decimals rounded with Baker's Rounding:

```
Value = CCur(0.567892)
' will return: 0.5679
```

so may have to either scale the stored values - save as Cent (x 100) and divide by 100 when reading:

```
Select ProductId, Format(PriceCent / 100, "$0.000000"), Description From Table
```

or you can save using Double as the data type. Note, however, that in general you should never use Double for any currency calculations due to the possible bit errors.

Also, should you have a serious need for rounding, you can use the set of functions here which never fails contrary to the many quick-n-dirty code pieces found when browsing:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://rdsrc.us/2Kmj0C)

**Author comment**

Changing the Price field to be Double Number  instead of currency allows me to have the 5 decimal accuracy on the unit price without having to scale. I tried to use DECIMAL which is in the Access SQL documentation but does not seem to be in the code. So I settled on Double. I only need to round it to 5 place accuracy in the calculations for pricing shopping lists. It seems this will be easier than scaling when I have to do the calculations.

Below is a code snippet of the new working code:

```
Const strPriceFormat As String = """$##0.00###"""
Const sqlVendorPriceList As String = "SELECT PricesLists.RecNo" & _
                                ", PricesLists.VendorNo AS VNo" & _
                                ", PricesLists.PartNo as Pno" & _
                                ", PricesLists.Quantity as Qty" & _
                                ", Format(PricesLists.Price, " & strPriceFormat & ") as Price" & _
                                " FROM PricesLists INNER JOIN VendorParts" & _
                                " ON PricesLists.PartNo=VendorParts.PartNo" & _
                                " AND PricesLists.VendorNo = VendorParts.VendorNo"
```

Comment: OK. In VBA, _Decimal_ is only available as a sub data type to _Variant_. If you wish to see examples for its use, study the link to the rounding functions I provided above, and you'll see a heavy use of `CDec` to obtain the high precision and zero errors of the functions.